# Python %mprun throws TypeError

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I'm having trouble getting the [Python memory line profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) to work. Whenever I run %mprun from within IPython, I get the error

```
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

I'm using the simplest example I can imagine.

```
In [1]: %load_ext memory_profiler
In [2]: from mpruntest import func
In [3]: A = rnd.randn(1000, 1000)
In [4]: %mprun -f func func(A)
```

Gives:

```
/Users/markvdw/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/memory_profiler.pyc in show_results(prof, stream, precision)
    600                                  'Line Contents')
    601 
--> 602         stream.write('Filename: ' + filename + '\n\n')
    603         stream.write(header + '\n')
    604         stream.write('=' * len(header) + '\n')

TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
```

`mpruntest` contains:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    y = x**2.0
    z = np.exp(y)
    return z
```

Comment: What if you try `stream.write('Filename: ' + unicode(filename) + '\n\n')`?

Comment: The error is thrown from within the `memory_profiler` code, I'm mostly wondering whether I'm doing something wrong or whether I should file a bug report.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken output with the `stream` for the part of your own script, so my suggestion is invalid. I personally do not see any problems with `mpruntest`. May be a bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug related to Python 2. I've just released a new version of memory_profiler (0.41) that should fix the problem. The output is now what you would expect:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
    11     42.5 MiB      0.0 MiB   def func(x):
    12     50.2 MiB      7.6 MiB       y = x**2.0
    13     57.8 MiB      7.6 MiB       z = np.exp(y)
    14     57.8 MiB      0.0 MiB       return z
```